# Asp Core TagHelper with default html attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

If I create my own TagHelper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("foobar")]
public class Foobar : TagHelper
{
}
```

and use it in my razor view:

```
<foobar onclick="test"></foobar>
```

the attribute 'onclick' isn't rendered if I examine this in my browser.

How can I create my own TagHelper with all the html default attributes available?

Thank you in advance

Comment: That's not a complete tag helper.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to get a list of all attributes on the existing tag and then merge them with your new tag.

```
var attributeList = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (var attribute in output.Attributes)
    attributeList.Add(attribute.Name, attribute.Value);

var anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
anchor.MergeAttributes(attributeList);

return anchor;
```

Seems like I'd run across a better way to do this, but after looking through my tag helpers I can't seem to find it.